# How to re-parse wikitext <math> tag using MathJax?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, mathjax

I have successfully parsed `<math>` tag to `$`. I want to re-parse `$` tag using Mathjax. For e.g,

`<math> x^2 + 1 </math>` is parsed to `$ x^2 + 1 $`, and I need to re-parse it using Mathjax to `x^2 + 1`. I did the parsing in [this Javascript file](https://github.com/Srijancse/OfflineExtension/blob/master/modules/wiky.js#L165). How do I re-parse it using MathJax?

So, this is the scene. Currently, I added code to my parser to parse wiki `<math>` tag to parse it to `$` so that MathJax can properly parse it to math formulae. How can I add Mathjax script in my JS?

Comment: Does it mean you want to match `$` followed with a space, then anything up to the first space followed with `$`? `replace(/\$\s.*?\s\$/g,'<math>$1</math>')`? The question is very unclear, please add specifications and your current code/pattern(s).

Comment: Currently that JS parses <math>anything</math> to $ anything $. I need to further parse it using MathJax.  How can I do that?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you check it again?

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear to me.

Comment: As Wiktor said, your question would benefit from clarification. MathJax parses input into a JavaScript object. It seems unlikely you are after that. Perhaps you just want to render can the TeX content using MathJax?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger True. I want to render the TeX content using MathJax